# how to create an ILArray in F#

Tags: f#, ilnumerics

this is what they do in C# to create an ILArray in C#

```
ILArray<double> A = 1.0;
```

how to make it in F#?

Comment: does `let A : ILArray<double> = 1.0` not work? what about `let A = new  ILArray<double>(1.0)`?

Comment: I suspect there will be ILArray<double>.op_Implicit involved somewhere

Comment: You may stick to the static creation functions within ILMath. See: http://ilnumerics.net/Arrays.html